# In what circumstances does getcwd() return NULL?

Tags: c, getcwd

```
char cwd[256];
if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) == NULL) {
    return -1;
}
```

First comes to mind that `getcwd()` could return `NULL`, when cwd is not large enough. Is there any other cases?

Comment: If you have a question about the exact semantics of a function, look at the relevant documentation spelling it out: The language-standard, the POSIX-standard, man-pages, MSDN, ... Asking someone to quote the page for you is lazy and not very useful. Besides, it takes longer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Its documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html) states:

> ```
> ERRORS
>
>     The getcwd() function shall fail if:
>
>     [EINVAL]
>         The size argument is 0.
>     [ERANGE]
>         The size argument is greater than 0, but is smaller than the length of the pathname +1.
>
>     The getcwd() function may fail if:
>
>     [EACCES]
>         Read or search permission was denied for a component of the pathname.
>     [ENOMEM]
>         Insufficient storage space is available.
> ```

Comment: POSIX.1-2008 (2013 Edition) => http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html (your link is to the 2004 edition of POSIX -- differences should be minimal anyway)

Answer (score 1):

```
 If the length of the absolute pathname of the  current  working  direc‐
       tory,  including the terminating null byte, exceeds size bytes, NULL is
       returned, and errno is set to ERANGE; an application should  check  for
       this error, and allocate a larger buffer if necessary.
```

source: man getcwd